# How to store user input into SQLite3 table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have a basic web page with two text boxes, one for the user's first name and the other for the user's last name. Once their name is entered, I want to save the data into a sqlite3 table via a button. The script I currently have in place is as follows:

```
<script>
            document.getElementById('btnSave').addEventListener('click', AddRecord);
            function AddRecord() 
            {               
                const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
                let db = new sqlite3.Database('C:/Users/RedCode/Documents/Programming Tutorials/Practice Site/test.db');
                var FirstName = document.getElementById('txtUsername').value;
                var LastName = document.getElementById('txtSurname').value;

                db.run('INSERT INTO testtbl(First_Name, Last_Name) VALUES("FirstName", "LastName")');

                db.close();
            }
        </script>
```

When I check the table, the data is not stored in it. What is the correct way to save that user's data into the table?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can achieve in browser. The tool you are trying to use is designed to be used with node which has access to the file system and can make calls to read and write from the sqlite.db file at will. Browsers cannot access the file system in this way.

If you really really need sqlite for real SQL type queries in your web app you can use something like: https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/ which is designed to be used in browser.

For regular storing of data in browser however there are inbuilt datastore tools

[Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)
[Index DB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)